# Java error on setLocation(x,y)

Tags: java

I am coding a simple mouse and cat game. 
But I always got a debug error when i try to use setLocation.

Can you tell me how can i fix it? i dont think there is anything wrong.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Random;

public abstract class Animal {

Point location_;
String name_;
Random rng_;

public Animal() {
}

 public Animal( String name, Random rng ){
    name_=name;
    rng_=rng;
}


abstract void move();

 public String getName(){
     return name_;
 }

 public Point getLocation(){
     return location_;
 }

 public void setStartLocation(){
     int x = rng_.nextInt(4);
     int y = rng_.nextInt(4);


// error 
    location_.setLocation(x, y);
 }

}
```

another file:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Cat extends Animal {



public Cat(String name, Random rng){
    super(name,rng);    
}


void move() {
    int i = rng_.nextInt(3);
    int x = (int) location_.getX();
    int y = (int) location_.getY();

    if(i==0 && y<4){

        int newY = y++;

        location_.move(x,newY);
    }

    else if (i==1 && y>0){

        int newY = y--;

        location_.move(x,newY);
    }

    else if (i==2 && x>0){

        int newX = x--;

        location_.move(newX,y);
    }

    else if (i==3 && x<4){

        int newX = x++;

        location_.move(newX,y);
    }

    else move();

}



}
```

another file:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Mouse extends Animal {

String mobility;

public Mouse(String name, Random rng){
    super(name,rng);    
}


void move() {
    int i = rng_.nextInt(3);
    int x = (int) location_.getX();
    int y = (int) location_.getY();

    if(i==0 ){

        int newY = y++;

        location_.move(x,newY);
    }

    else if (i==1){

        int newY = y--;

        location_.move(x,newY);
    }

    else if (i==2){

        int newX = x--;

        location_.move(newX,y);
    }

    else if (i==3){

        int newX = x++;

        location_.move(newX,y);
    }



}

public String checkMoblity(){
    int x = (int) location_.getX();
    int y = (int) location_.getY();

    if(x==-1 || x==5){
        if(y==0 || y==2 || y==4){
            return "drowned";
        }

        else return "escaped";
    }

    else if(y==-1 || y==5){
        if(x==0 || x==2 || x==4){
            return "drowned";
        }

        else return "escaped";
    }

    else  return null;

}

}
```

another file:

```
 import java.util.Random;

public class Chase {

public  void playGame(){

    Random rand = new Random();

//error
    Cat cat = new Cat("Tom", rand);
    Mouse mouse = new Mouse("Jerry", rand);

    do{
        cat.setStartLocation();
        mouse.setStartLocation();
    }while(cat.getLocation()== mouse.getLocation());

    String status = Status(cat,mouse);
    boolean end = end(cat, mouse);

    do{
        mouse.move();

        if(end==false){
        cat.move();
        }

    }while(end==false);

    if (status == "drowned"){
        System.out.println(mouse.getName() + " drowned!");
    }

    else if (status == "escaped"){
        System.out.println(mouse.getName() + " escaped!");
    }

    else if (status == "snack"){
        System.out.println(cat.getName() + " got the snack!");
    }


}



public  String Status(Cat cat, Mouse mouse){
    if(mouse.checkMoblity()== "drowned"){
        return "drowned";
    }

    else if(mouse.checkMoblity() == "escaped"){
        return "escaped";
    }

    else if(mouse.getLocation()==cat.getLocation()){
        return "snack";
    }

    else return null;
}

public  boolean end(Cat cat, Mouse mouse){
    if(mouse.checkMoblity()== "drowned"){
        return true;
    }

    else if(mouse.checkMoblity() == "escaped"){
        return true;
    }

    else if(mouse.getLocation()==cat.getLocation()){
        return true;
    }

    else return false;
}



public static void main(String[] args){
    Chase chase = new Chase();

//error
    chase.playGame();
}
}
```

Comment: I bet you are getting null pointer exception?

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [instantiate an object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) before using it :

```
public void setStartLocation(){
    int x = rng_.nextInt(4);
    int y = rng_.nextInt(4);

    location_ = new Point(x, y);
}
```

The setter method `setLocation(int, int)` cannot be used if your object `Point location_` is not instantiated.

Comment: I tried this. it works. however when I try to debug or run my project, nothing happened. I might got new problem.

Comment: What is your new problem ? Could you explain more ?

Comment: I fixed my code as what you said. I am using Eclipse to write my code. I clicked Run as Java project, nothing happened.

Comment: Are you running your main class `Chase` ? Try to click _Run as_ when `Chase.java` file is selected.

Comment: Yes, i did.  And there is also nothing happened when debug

Comment: No, things are happening when debug. You can see it by adding `System.out.println("your message here..");` in your code, especially in the `do ... while` loop of the mouse and cat moves. I've tested your code: that `do ... while`  loop is set to `end==false`, which means loop never ends, that's why your cannot see the results below.

Comment: I'm afraid I need to go now. Hope my tips help you, happy coding !

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Emm. last question.  I found that actually the mouse and cat always stay at a point and never move. Does it because there is some problem in my random number generator?

Comment: I found it ! You're using operator `i++` to increment the value for x and y, but `int newY = y++;` means that you give the current value of `y` to `newY`, then `y = y + 1`. So the solution is to do `int newY = y + 1;` or more elegant `int newY = ++y;`

Comment: I  just solved them all. However, I found that my checkStatus in mouse class doent work. it always return null.

Comment: I don't see the method `checkStatus()` in your provided class `Mouse`. If you mean `checkMoblity()`, then check if its conditions are correct.

Comment: conditions are correct.  But I just wonder if I made some syntax error.

Comment: I don't think it is a syntax error. Syntax errors will be thrown as exceptions, but returning `null` is more your subjective choice. If you think it worths as a question, you can create another post.

Comment: emm. sorry, it said i cannot post today.

Comment: You've a `else  return null;` statement in your class `Mouse`'s method `checkMoblity()`

Comment: I delete it, it said the function need a return type of string.

Comment: Are you returning an integer `int` ? If yes, then cast it to `String`.